# Paste special text leaves trailing spaces in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, paste

I wrote a script that creates an HTML table like this for a coworker:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>06/21/2014</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06/22/2014</td>
        <td>BBB</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06/23/2014</td>
        <td>CCC</td>        
    </tr>       
</table>
```

When she pastes it into Excel, she either gets this:

```
|6/21/2014|AAA|
|6/22/2014|BBB|
|6/23/2014|CCC|
```

Where the date strings have had the preceding 0 removed, this breaks a find/replace we're trying to do on dates. Or, if she tries to paste special -> text on her windows PC she gets this:

```
|06/21/2014|AAA |
|06/22/2014|BBB |
|06/23/2014|CCC |
```

If I paste special on a mac, it works fine. Is there a way to:

1. turn off default auto date formatting for all new files?
   OR
2. make the paste special text stop adding trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to tell Excel to NOT try automatic data type determination, then simply add a `'` character before the data you enter into a cell.

When using paste, the `'` might end up be visible though. A search and replace on `'` to `'` (from and to being the same) might help to remedy that (not tried).